# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.values

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos de firebase de terceros, y me funcionaba todo bien hasta que quise aplicar axios.delete para remover los datos. En ese momento se me borro toda la base de datos y me sale null.. ahora me figura este error en pantalla: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.values ()  at solicitudActions.js:58.

Les muestro el codigo donde me figura el error:

```
    export function obtenerSolicitudAction() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(obtenerSolicitud());

    try {
      const respuesta = await clienteAxios.get("/users.json");
      //console.log(Object.values(respuesta.data));
      if (respuesta === null) {
        return [];
      } else {
        dispatch(descargaSolicitudExito(Object.values(respuesta.data)));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch(descargaSolicitudError());
    }
  };
}
```

Y aqui el del axios.delete:

```
 export function eliminarSolicitudAction(id) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(eliminarSolicitud(id));

    try {
      const resultado = await clienteAxios.delete("/users.json", {
        params: { foo: `${id}` },
      });
      console.log(resultado);
      dispatch(eliminarSolicitudExito());
    } catch (error) {}
  };
}
```

Y por utlimo, donde estoy iterando, que puede ser que este mal tambien:

```
 <tbody>
          {solicitudes === 0
            ? "no hay solicitudes"
            : solicitudes.map((solicitud, id) => (
                <Solicitudes key={id} solicitud={solicitud} />
              ))}
        </tbody>
```

He buscado pero no encuentro la solucion, y ahora no me deja ingresar datos en la BD ni nada.. les agradeceria si me orientan un poco! gracias!

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Pienso que `respuesta` puede ser `undefined` luego de la llamada a `clienteAxios.get("/users.json");`, pero solo evaluas `null`. Que imprime si haces un `console.log(respuesta)` antes del `if`?

Comment: El mismo error, pero ahora me avisa de un error tambien en la conexion a la api, la cual me sigue dando null y no se ven los datos.

Comment: ¿De las líneas que publicas, cúal es la 58 a la que hace referencia el error?

Comment: dispatch(descargaSolicitudExito(Object.values(respuesta.data))); es ésta linea

Comment: es mas, si le agrego {} antes de respuesta.data ---dispatch(descargaSolicitudExito(Object.values({}, respuesta.data))); --- se me va el error, pero sigo sin poder agregar datos a la api y la misma me figura null... no se que fue lo que paso

Comment: Quizás haga falta que cambies la condición a algo como: `if ((typeof respuesta == 'undefined') || (respuesta === null) || (respuesta.data === null))`. Por lo que veo, si tienes una variable respuesta, pero su `data` es null.

Answer (score 0):

Si como dices, se borró la información, claramente no va a retornarte nada, tampoco es que te esté retornando 4xx o 5xx el request, porque el `catch` sucede dentro del código del `else`, así que el servidor debe estar retornando un 200 con simplemente lo que encontró que es nada.

Y el error que mencionas es consecuencia de eso, Estás tratando de obtener los valores de objeto de `respuesta.data`, cuando no viene nada ahí.

```js
const respuesta = {data: null}
Object.values(respuesta.data)
```

Creo que una forma de manejar esto sería verificar también que vengan datos en la respuesta:

```
  if (respuesta === null || respuesta.data === null) {
    return [];
  } else {
    dispatch(descargaSolicitudExito(Object.values(respuesta.data)));
  }
```